# Adding space between inline-block buttons

Tags: html, css

New to HTML/CSS, I would like to add some spaces between inline buttons I created. Not sure how to do this.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="..\Requests\Request" class="button">Standard Request</a>

<a href="..\Requests\PlannerUpload" class="button">Bulk or Special Request</a>

<a href="..\Requests\NewPlannerDevice" class="button">New Device Request</a>

<a href="..\Requests\Requesttest" class="button">Tester Request</a>
```

This code produces what is seen in this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOdgZ.png)

Comment: How about adding some margin-right to your links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding margin ?

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="..\Requests\Request" class="button">Standard Request</a>

<a href="..\Requests\PlannerUpload" class="button">Bulk or Special Request</a>

<a href="..\Requests\NewPlannerDevice" class="button">New Device Request</a>

<a href="..\Requests\Requesttest" class="button">Tester Request</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `margin-right` on your `.button`:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right:20px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="..\Requests\Request" class="button">Standard Request</a>

<a href="..\Requests\PlannerUpload" class="button">Bulk or Special Request</a>

<a href="..\Requests\NewPlannerDevice" class="button">New Device Request</a>

<a href="..\Requests\Requesttest" class="button">Tester Request</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-right: 20px; to your .button class

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin to your ".button {...}" in your stylesheet.

```
margin: 5%;
```

The % doesn't really matter, but use it rather than pixels so it has a more diverse reach across screen sizes.

Answer (score -2):

Modify your code as follows:
You need to add margin

```
.button {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 25px 35px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      Margin-right : 10px;
    }

    .button:hover {
      background-color: green;
    }
```